# how to display validation in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I want to display a validation check when name is empty.

Here is the code

```
 state = {
    name: "",
    nameFeedback: false,
    nameValidationMessage: ""
  };
  nameValidator = () => {
    this.setState({
      nameFeedback: true
    });
    const newName = `${this.name.value || ''}`.trim();
    if (newName === "") {
        this.setState({
        name: false,
        nameValidationMessage: "Name cannot be empty"
      });
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          ref={(input) => {
            this.name = input;
          }}
          onBlur={this.nameValidator}
        />
        {this.state.nameFeedBack && !this.state.name && (
          <small className="help-block">
            {this.state.nameValidationMessage || "This value is not valid"}
          </small>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

When I leave the input box without typing any characters,it is not displaying the error.

Answer (score 0):

there is a spelling mistake in this setState

```
 this.setState({
  nameFeedback: true
  });
```

replace by

```
this.setState({
        nameFeedBack: true
    });
```